# How to include module/test interface/test roles in RSpec? Translating POODR test code from Minitest to RSpec

Tags: rspec, module, minitest

I want to translate Sandi Metz's final test code in "POODR" from Minitest to RSpec. In Chapter 9, she checks if any object that "includes DiameterizableInterfaceTest" has a "diameter" method. Here, it checks if both DiameterDouble and Wheel have "diameter" methods:

```
module DiameterizableInterfaceTest
  def test_implements_the_diameterizable_interface
    assert_respond_to(@object, :diameter)
  end
end

class DiameterDouble
  def diameter
    10
  end
end

class DiameterDoubleTest < MiniTest::Test
  include DiameterizableInterfaceTest

  def setup
    @object = DiameterDouble.new
  end
end

class WheelTest < MiniTest::Test
  include DiameterizableInterfaceTest

  def setup
    @wheel = @object = Wheel.new(26, 1.5)
  end

  def test_calculates_diameter
    assert_in_delta(29,
                    @wheel.diameter,
                    0.01)
  end
end
```

This works. Just that 1 line, "include DiameterizableInterfaceTest," does it. However, I can't do the same thing in RSpec. I tried:

```
module DiameterizableInterfaceTest
  describe 'object has diameter method' do
    it 'implements diameterizable interface' do
      expect(object).to respond_to(:diameter)
    end
  end
end

class DiameterDouble
  def diameter
    10
  end
end

describe DiameterDouble do
  include DiameterizableInterfaceTest
  let (:object) { DiameterDouble.new }
end
```

But all combinations of "object" in the module fail. If I use "object," it says "undefined local variable or method `object'." For "@object," it says "expected nil to respond to :diameter." For ":object," it says "expected :object to respond to :diameter."

To include that module in RSpec, the only thing that works is if I change the "describe" block to a method, like this. This forces me to add an it-block for "has_diameter_method?" for every class I check, which is ridiculous and wordy:

```
module DiameterizableInterfaceTest
  def has_diameter_method?
    expect(@object).to respond_to(:diameter)
  end
end

class DiameterDouble
  def diameter
    10
  end
end

describe DiameterDouble do
  include DiameterizableInterfaceTest
  before do
    @object = DiameterDouble.new
  end

  it 'has diameter method' do
    has_diameter_method?
  end
end

describe Wheel do
  include DiameterizableInterfaceTest

  describe '#diameter' do
    before do
      @wheel = @object = Wheel.new(26, 1.5)
    end
    it 'calculates diameter' do
      expect(@wheel.diameter).to eq(29)
    end

    it 'has diameter method' do
      has_diameter_method?
    end
  end
end
```

How do I include modules in multiple class tests in RSpec, the way I did in Minitest, without adding this extra it-block? In Minitest, I could add this check for each class with 1 line, "include DiameterizableInterfaceTest." In RSpec, it takes 4 more lines.

Here's [another example](http://www.cyrusinnovation.com/find-all-the-implementations-of-a-role-with-role-tests/) of what I want to do. It's easy in Minitest but not in RSpec.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out the answer! Thank you, CodeSchool: http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/4/challenges/4

My RSpec solution: https://github.com/rayning0/poodr/blob/master/spec/ch9g_spec.rb

The key was to use `shared_examples`, which allows for a generic object ("it"). In the test, I use `it_behaves_like` to check all behaviors in shared_examples. Also, for Wheel, I needed to add `subject { wheel }`, or it would say `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`.

```
shared_examples 'Diameterizable' do
  it { should respond_to(:diameter) }
end

class DiameterDouble
  def diameter
    10
  end
end

describe DiameterDouble do
  it_behaves_like 'Diameterizable'
  let(:object) { DiameterDouble.new }
end

describe Wheel do
  it_behaves_like 'Diameterizable'
  let(:wheel) { Wheel.new(26, 1.5) }
  subject { wheel }

  it 'calculates diameter' do
    expect(wheel.diameter).to eq(29)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at rspec's "shared examples": https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Comment: Thank you, Spencer! I figured it out! Here's my answer: https://github.com/rayning0/poodr/blob/master/spec/ch9g_spec.rb. Thank you, CodeSchool: http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/4/challenges/4